# Not Fount :/media/app/images/my_image.png

Tags: django, django-templates

image not found but the image exist at exact location .

```
print(profile.image.url)
#/media/app/images/my_image.png
```

prints the image location but when i used in my template , other column are 
current but image is not found

```
profile = same_table.object.get(pk = 1)
```

setting:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(MY_BASE_DIR , 'media')
```

my media location has no problem because when i upload image to server 
it is working fine

Template:

```
<img src = "{{profile.image.url}}">
```

any idea what i messed ?

Using Django 1.10 with Python 3.4 in window 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to end of your root urls config `urls.py` this:

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```